# I can't get the guild name in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I can't get the guild name. It's weird that the code works fine in other files and I don't know what's the problem. Please help!
PS. `player.guild` work's fine. I tested it with console.log and it returns the guild id so I don't know the problem. PSS. I'm using discord.js v12
The code:

```
const gd = bot.guilds.cache.get(player.guild).name
console.log(gd)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: `.get` takes the key, `player.guild` probably isn't the key, you should use the guild ID instead

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti that's the thing... player.guild.id it s undefined. I need to use just player.guild bc it's returning the key and if I m trying to use `const gd = bot.guilds.cache.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").name` I  get the same error

Comment: Where does `player.guild` come from?

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti from erela.js

Comment: with event `.on("trackStart", (player, track) => {`

Comment: and I repeat... player.guild works fine

Comment: Can you log `player.guild`?